# WebApi to Angular Property Keys are coming in all lower case?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, http

When sending my properties in an HttpGet call all of them are coming in lowercase once they hit angular. How can I prevent this from happening

```
       [HttpGet]
        public List<MyModel> GetModel()
        {
            var model = _repo.GetModel();
            return model;
        }


      public Class MyModel
          {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;}
          }
```

these are coming into angular like this

```
   return this.httpClient.get<any>( this.myEndPoint + '/GetMyModel');
    { id: 1, name: "John" }
```

I need them to stay the exact same case they are sent in

```
{ Id: 1, Name: "John" }
```

Comment: if you're using .net core.... https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-json-output-camelcase-pascalcase/

Comment: Using plain ole web api. No .net core this time

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking is more specific to your API that's returning the data, not angular or JavaScript. Since you're working with C#, you have a couple of options:

1.) `JsonProperty` attribute. You could decorate your model with `JsonProperty("Id")`. Full disclosure, I have not tested this part, but it should work. There's a chance the `JsonSerializationSettings` might overwrite this. If so, see #2.

2.) Define custom `JsonSerializationSettings` to use Pascal Case instead of the default CamlCase

It's kind of strange the only option offered by default is CamelCase, so you have to create your own Json Naming Policy.

Example if you wanted camel case

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions( options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase )
```

So, you have to do this on your own (Example of Upper Case):

```
public class UpperCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name) =>
        name.ToUpper();
}
```

Usage:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new UpperCaseNamingPolicy(),
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, options);
```

See this for more explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#customize-json-names-and-values

Comment: should be marked as correct answer